# How do I digitally sign PDFs in 2019?

Tags: encryption, libreoffice, pdf, open-source

[This older post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147379/how-do-i-digitally-sign-a-pdf) is either pointing to mostly dead software or the answers are not fully applicable.

I want to take a PDF document, stick in an image of my signature and have this be digitally signed using a certificate so that the document is secured and any changes will be picked up.

I'd like to open a document, navigate to the relevant signature page, click on the line or draw a box, enter a password and my signature should be drawn and certificate used to digitally sign the doc.

I've tried the following options and here are the problems:

- Libre Office: Difficult to sign existing PDF's, better to create pdf's with. Have to add signature image separately.
- PortableSigner: Hard to position signature but does the job
- Master PDF Editor: Works well but takes 70 dollars to prevent ugly watermark being added to PDF's
- Foxit Reader: Only adds image without any certificate signing.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://vmiklos.hu/blog/pdf-sign.html libreoffice does not seem too difficult ;) It is the go-to software for making documents, making the pdf from it and so also for signing it. And totally free "Any ideas?" get better at using LO? >:-D

Comment: Cool, updated to Libre-Office 6, tried to add certificate, get the "password incorrect for Gnome2 Key Storage" error. Try to force certificates to be recognised. That fails too. Yeah, doesn't seem too difficult. Actually is.

Comment: That is not a problem with LO I would think. The 2 (LO and keyring) give me zero results... stumped for now but I will keep looking if I can find something ;-)

Comment: LibreOffice made it slightly easier -- but there's a new/old bug preventing from new version (1.5+) PDFs to be signed (as of today, v6.4.3.2)

Comment: If you like programming, you can try the endesive package of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also want to take a look at my [Simple Signer](https://github.com/schorschii/Simple-Signer). In addition to LibreOffice Draw, it can also add a visual stamp onto the document (which is linked to your signature) as known from the Adobe Reader.

In addition to that, you can choose if you want to sign or certify your document.

Comment: This looks pretty good. I'm going to mark this as the answer even though I haven't tried it... I really don't want more mails on this.

Answer (score 2):

I use DocuSign, which is free web app (for single signatures). It also serves as a (hopefully) trusted third party.

From [DocuSign - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocuSign):

> DocuSign, Inc. is an American company headquartered in San Francisco, California that allows organizations to manage electronic agreements. As part of the DocuSign Agreement Cloud, DocuSign offers eSignature, a way to sign electronically on different devices. DocuSign claims it has over 475,000 customers and hundreds of millions of users in more than 180 countries. Signatures processed by DocuSign are compliant with the US ESIGN Act. and the European Union's eIDAS regulation, including EU Advanced and EU Qualified Signatures.

Comment: I definitely recommend DocuSign! Dropbox has HelloSign that's built-in to the Dropbox application for Ubuntu as well (3 free signings a month).

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/q/167274/349837)'s how to add a picture into an existing PDF file.

I would sign the pdf with [GNU Privacy Guard](https://gnupg.org/) (GPG). There is [a list of frontends](https://gnupg.org/software/frontends.html), I use [GNU Privacy Assistant](https://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpa/) (GPA, `apt install gpa`). It works pretty well.

Comment: Would be good to share how that's done

Comment: Exist some issues [with this approach](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147379/how-do-i-digitally-sign-a-pdf-with-a-s-mime-certificate#comment1539143_608449). Another frontend alternative is [Kleopatra](https://apps.kde.org/kleopatra/) (idem package)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you go through the list of [OpenSC based applications](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Using-smart-cards-with-applications). OpenSC is the base library of most applications using smartcard and USB key hardware certificates.

At first glance, the following seem interesting for your use case (though I haven't tried them myself yet):

- [j4sign](http://j4sign.sourceforge.net/), still in active development
- [Sinadura](http://www.sinadura.net/en/inicio)
- [cryptonit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cryptonit/)

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to open a document, navigate to the relevant signature page, click on the line or draw a box, enter a password and my signature should be drawn and certificate used to digitally sign the doc.

Web based Online interactive Digital Signing solution available for free use, which can sign interactively by drawing rectangle.  Digital Certificate can be picked from client's USB Token or Smartcard on Linux clients and is available at https://web.signer.digital

If you are developer, the components (browser extension, again free to use) may also be integrated with any server side pdf library in your web applications.

Answer (score 0):

You need a (free) adobe.com account, but you can upload your PDFs to https://documentcloud.adobe.com and use their 'Fill & Sign' tool. Probably a bit clumsy if you have a lot of PDFs to manage, but it's a quick route to getting the job done for infrequent PDF users like me.

Answer (score -1):

You create in LibreOffice your usual document as new document (*.doc or *.odt) - when document is created finish, then add watermark like it is described here :

https://libreofficehelp.com/how-to-add-watermark-in-libreoffice-writer/

When watermark is set finish, you then can export this document to format PDF.

Comment: This doesn't address signing documents. I was talking about signing existing pdf's with an image of a signature, not a watermark, and then using a certificate to ensure that changes post signature are picked up. Watermarks do none of that.