# LibreOffice fails to access my personal certificate

Tags: libreoffice, certificates, signature

Recently, I updated my personal certificate. Then I wanted to sign a libreoffice document.

I followed the [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122058/how-do-i-make-a-digital-certificate-available-to-libreoffice-writer-for-digital) from Part 1 to Part 4. Both Thunderbird and Firefox are displaying the correct, up-to-date certificate. But Libreoffice (5.1.6.2, xenial4) shows still only the outdated one (with the Firefox:default option) or nothing (with thunderbird:default option).

Edit: I've already found out the [reason](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/147842/digital-signature-after-mozzila-firefox-change-cert-and-key-files-format/): different cert and key file formats used by mozzila resp. LO, in place since spring 2018. But no way how to solve it :-O

Answer (score 2):

A stupid solution, bud worked. 
I've installed the certificate in old Firefox 55 --> generated key and cert files ---> LibreOffice liked them.
Uninstalled FF55.
Hope there is no security issue.